# hive query avro uniontype

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

Similar to [hive querying records for a specific uniontype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362110/hive-querying-records-for-a-specific-uniontype)

I have data on s3 in avro format and following is the avro structure:

```js
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Event",
  "namespace": "com.company.avro.event",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "content",
      "type": [
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Follow",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "content",
              "type": [
                {
                  "type": "record",
                  "name": "UserFollowBrand",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "name": "id",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "actor",
                      "type": "com.company.avro.entity.User"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "verb",
                      "type": "string",
                      "default": "UserFollowBrand"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "direct_object",
                      "type": "com.company.avro.entity.Brand"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "on",
                      "type": [
                        "com.company.avro.type.IoSScreen",
                        "com.company.avro.type.AndroidScreen",
                        "null"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "using",
                      "type": "com.company.avro.entity.App"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "from",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "at",
                      "type": "long"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "type": "record",
                  "name": "UserFollowUser",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "name": "id",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "actor",
                      "type": "com.company.avro.entity.User"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "verb",
                      "type": "string",
                      "default": "UserFollowUser"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "direct_object",
                      "type": "com.company.avro.entity.User"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "on",
                      "type": [
                        "com.company.avro.type.IoSScreen",
                        "com.company.avro.type.AndroidScreen",
                        "null"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "using",
                      "type": "com.company.avro.entity.App"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "from",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "at",
                      "type": "long"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Like",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "content",
              "type": [
                {
                  "type": "record",
                  "name": "UserLikeListing",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "name": "id",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "actor",
                      "type": "com.company.avro.entity.User"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "verb",
                      "type": "string",
                      "default": "UserLikeListing"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "direct_object",
                      "type": "com.company.avro.entity.Listing"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "on",
                      "type": [
                        "com.company.avro.type.IoSScreen",
                        "com.company.avro.type.AndroidScreen",
                        "com.company.avro.type.WebScreen",
                        "null"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "using",
                      "type": "com.company.avro.entity.App"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "from",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "at",
                      "type": "long"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure how can I query for specific field within the uniontype.

For ex: `select * from events where content.verb = "a" and content.actor.id = 34`

Earlier hive did not support union types but now it seems it does support https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2390

Unable to figure out how to use `create_union` function to query this.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-UnionTypes

Comment: one way is create UDF the other is to write a custom deserializer. Are there not simpler options ?